# How to create a method of a structure in golang that is called automatically?

Tags: oop, constructor, initialization, go, structure

I have to create a something like a substitute of 2 levels of inheritance in golang, i.e.,
in a package, I have a structure(**A**), which is inherited(embedded as an anonymous field) by another structure(**B**) in another package, whose object is to be utilized by the "**main**" package.

Now, I've created an initializer method for the "B" (**BPlease**) that returns an object of B (say,**B_obj**). I can call this initializer(**BPlease**) from my "main" package at the start of the program.

One of the methods of "B" (say, **HelloB()**), calls a method of "A"(say,**HelloA()**) during execution, using "B's" object.

But what I really want is, something like a constructor for "A" that can initialize its fields (preferably when B_obj was created in package "main") before "B" calls any methods of "A".

How to achieve this?

I tried creating an initializer(**APlease**) for "A" as well and called it (**BPlease**) to get an object of "A" (A_obj). But I found this object useless as I couldn't utilize it to call "A's" method (HelloA()) inside a method of "B" (HelloB()). 
It would be great if someone can tell me how to utilize this object (A_obj).

Here's some code to clarify my query:

```
    package A
    type A struct { whatever }
    func (A_obj *A) HelloA(){performs some operation...}           // a method of A()
    func APlease() A {
          return A{initialize A fields}
        }
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    package B
    type B struct {
      A
      B fields
    }

    func BPlease() B {
      return B{
      A_obj := APlease()                     // useless to me.... how to utilise this?
      initialize B fields}
    }

    func (B_obj *B) HelloB(){                            // a method of B{}
      call B_obj.HelloA()                         // valid as A is an anon field in B struct
      some other operations                       // but A's fields are not initialized for B_obj
...}         

---------------------------------------------------
package main

import "B"
import "A"

func main(){
  B_obj := B.BPlease()         // what I want is, calling this should initialize A's fields for B_obj as well so that when HelloB() calls B_obj.HelloA(), it utilises A's field that have been initialized.
}
```

I cannot pass all field-values as parameters to B_obj as there are a lot of fields, and also, some field values are generated by calling a method of the same structure.

Comment: I think some pieces of code would make it easier to illustrate what you want, and why you need it.

Answer (score 9):

Regardless of anyone's opinion about fighting the language to have inheritance when it doesn't: No, there are no *magic* methods, like "getter" or "setter" of whatever. Remotely related (magic powers) are perhaps finalizers, but they're surely not going to help in this case.

However, let me suggest to stop coding language X in Go. Just use Go. Go doesn't use "class-like" inheritance, nor a Go programmer (usually) should. Think of Go like a modernized C. There's no much C code out there relying on inheritance. (OK, I know about GObject ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Some meta-remark: "First structure" and "second structure" make it very hard to understand which one is which. Labeling the different things like A, B and C is the tool which make math so powerful.

Is this your question:
You have two type A and B, B embeds A. You want to make sure B is "fully initialized" in the sense of A is also initialized.

Raw sketch:

```
type A struct { whatever }
type B struct {
  A
  more stuff
}

func APlease(params for an A) A {
  return A{fields set up from params}
}

func BPlease(params forn an A and for an B) B {
  return B{
    A: APlease(stuff for A),
    more: set from params for B,
  }
}
```

Should do this: You can ask for a proper set up B by calling `BPlease` with the necessary parameters for both, the embedded A and the rest of B.

Comment: There is a naming convention for construction functions, which are not quite 'constructors' in the OO sense, but are similar. `APlease` would conventionally be called `NewA` and `BPlease` would be `NewB`. There are lots of examples of this convention in the standard Go API (some of which tersely use `New(<params>)`. Another example is here http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals.

Comment: @Volker Thanks for your answer and suggestion. I've edited the question. Though passing values as parameters can achieve this, but its impractical in my situation. I've a lot of fields and many are initialized by calling methods of same structure.

Comment: I understand. You want to do something which is impossible. Think of it this way: How on earth could B construct its A? B must "know" how to construct A. How? Either pass arguments (you said you can't, smth I don't believe), or let a zero A be useful (compare bytes.Buffer or sync.Mutex) or have some global state to build A from. Jnml is right: There is no black magic in Go.

Comment: *Sigh* okay! I'll try the arguments thing. I'll post here later about what design I decided. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Volker's answer a bit, you should be able to call

```
func BPlease() B {
  a_obj := A.APlease() // initialize the fields of A like normal
  b_obj := B{} // create a B, whose anonymous fields are not initialized yet

  b_obj.A = a_obj // PERHAPS WHAT YOU WANT: copy all a's fields to b's fields.
                  // if you are relying sending a_obj's address somewhere in 
                  // APlease(), you may be out of luck.

  b_obj.field_unique_to_B = "initialized"
  return b_obj
}
```

Now that you can create B objects with fields initialized by APlease(), you can call A's methods on B's objects, and even call A's methods from within B like so:

```
func (B_obj *B) HelloB(){
  // can't call B_obj.HelloA() like you would expect
  B_obj.A.HelloA() // this works. Go "promotes" the anonymous field's methods 
                   // and fields to B_obj
                   // but they don't appear in B_obj, they appear in B_obj.A 
  fmt.Printf("And hello from B too; %s", B_obj.field_unique_to_B)
}
```

I will echo Rick-777 here and suggest you stick to go's naming conventions and idioms; NewReader is much easier to read and understand than ReaderPlease.

I contrived an example that I can put on bitbucket if people want. I think it's much easier to read when you are working with real metaphors; also a disclaimer - this is not the best code, but it does some things that answer your question.

file: car/car.go

```
package car

import "fmt"

type BaseCar struct {
    Doors  int // by default, 4 doors. SportsCar will have 2 doors
    Wheels int
}

func NewBaseCar() BaseCar {
    return BaseCar{Wheels: 4, Doors: 4}
}

// this will be used later to show that a "subclass" can call methods from self.BaseCar
func (c *BaseCar) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("BaseCar: %d doors, %d wheels", c.Doors, c.Wheels)
}

// this will be promoted and not redefined
func (c *BaseCar) CountDoors() int {
    return c.Doors
}
```

file sportscar/sportscar.go

```
package sportscar

// You can think of SportsCar as a subclass of BaseCar. But go does
// not have conventional inheritence, and you can paint yourself into
// a corner if you try to force square c++ structures into round go holes.

import ( "../car" ; "fmt" )

type SportsCar struct {
    car.BaseCar // here is the anonymous field
    isTopDown   bool
}

func NewSportsCar() SportsCar {
    conv := SportsCar{} // conv.Wheels == 0

    conv.BaseCar = car.NewBaseCar() // now conv.Wheels == conv.Doors == 4

    conv.isTopDown = false // SportsCar-only field
    conv.Doors = 2         // Fewer Doors than BaseCar
    return conv
}

// SportsCar only method
func (s *SportsCar) ToggleTop() {
    s.isTopDown = !s.isTopDown
}

// "overloaded" string method note that to access the "base" String() method, 
// you need to do so through the anonymous field: s.BaseCar.String()
func (s *SportsCar) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Sports%s, topdown: %t", s.BaseCar.String(), s.isTopDown)
}
```

file main.go

```
package main

import ( "./car" ; "./sportscar" ; "fmt")

type Stringer interface { // added this complication to show
    String() string // that each car calls its own String() method
}

func main() {
    boring := car.NewBaseCar()
    fancy := sportscar.NewSportsCar()

    fmt.Printf("      %s\n", Stringer(&boring))
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", Stringer(&fancy))
    fancy.ToggleTop()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", Stringer(&fancy))

    fmt.Println("BaseCar.CountDoors() method is callable from a SportsCar:", fancy.CountDoors())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are ways to mimic inheritance in Go if this is what you are looking for, see section "Inheritance" in this [blog](http://objectscape.blogspot.de/2015/02/is-googles-go-object-oriented-now-or-not.html)